# how to have Bootstrap make my component drop below another component

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I think I get the basics of bootstrap and how to assign sizes to colums. But somehow I don't seem to solve this simple usecase.

Usecase :

I have 2 components, let's say for a Todo-list application:

- component 'New Todo' (Form Input field)
- component 'Todo List' (Table List)

I would like to achieve that on **large screens** the 'New Todo' component is on the right (taking half the screen) and the 'Todo List' component is on the left (taking also half of the screen).

But on **small (mobile) screens**, the 'New Todo' component should be on the top and the 'Todo List' component should move below it.

Extra question : how can I make the 'New Todo' input field collapsable on small mobile screens ?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. You're expected to show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No really need Bootstrap for that.
You can wrap the two components in a display:flex container and change the order property in a media query for mobile.

But if you really want to use Bootstrap, here is the link to [Bootstrap flex utilities.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.new-todo,
.todo-list {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
  flex: 50%
}

@media (max-width:480px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .new-todo,
  .todo-list {
    flex: 100%
  }
  .new-todo {
    order: 1
  }
  .todo-list {
    order: 2
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="todo-list">todo-list</div>
  <div class="new-todo">new-todo</div>
</div>


With Bootstrap:<br>

<div class="row flex-wrap flex-lg-nowrap">
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-2 order-lg-1">todo-list</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-6 order-1 order-lg-2">new-todo</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you,  but I really would like to stick with Bootstrap.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example with bootstrap 5 (should also work with version 4).